# HTTP Strict Transport Security on openshift

Tags: security, https, http-headers, openshift

How do I enable HTTP Strict Transport Security on openshift portal? I am working on a php application and not very sure where to make this setting. I believe I need access to Apache configuration file to achieve this - which I don't think openshift allows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create an `.htaccess` file and add the HSTS header there.

```
# Force https
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Add HSTS header
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that's it. I'll just wait a bit and mark the answer. I have been hearing some talk about trying not to rely too much on htaccess. I haven't researched that a lot though.

Comment: Modifying .htacess is the recommended way to make changes to the Apache configuration on OpenShift as httpd.conf is not editable. However, you can just set a Strict-Transport-Security header using PHP: `<?php
header('Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000'); ?>`. The PHP-based approach makes much less sense in my opinion.